# WebStorm/PhpStorm is not aware of external changes

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 9 in Windows 10. I have configured **Automatic Upload** to my FTP server even for the **external changes**. The problem is that PhpStorm is not aware of these changes while the window is not active/focused. So, when I transpile LESS or TypeScript, I have to switch to a different window and go back to get my output files uploaded.

Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, it expected (more or less; *especially* if IDE is not active window/focused) -- IDE does not scan your file system all the time, especially if you are keeping your files over network (e.g. shared folders) or using symlinks. You can force rescan manually by invoking `File | Synchronize` (basically the same happens when you switching to IDE window from another app).

Comment: what way do you use to transpile LESS or TypeScript? is it done in webstorm, with file watchers or integrated build tools (gulp, grunt)? Or, do you do it externally, outside of the IDE?

Comment: I'm using a gulp task.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile LESS into css with internal tool of PHPStorm.
This is the file watcher tools : [File Watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-file-watchers.html)

You can install ruby and nodeJS in your windows environnement and locate the binary of less or scss which noticed in PHPStorm.

Just tell it where do you want to copy the result of compile locate in your project.

You must delivery the less file into your webserver if you want to view directly the change with engine of compile less also in you webserver environment.